# How do you limit the y-axis height in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do you limit the height of the y-axis in matplotlib figure? I am trying to both display the x axis, and reduce the height of the figure for this 1D plot.

I have tried setting ticks, figure sizes, tight_layout, margin, etc. with no luck.

Also, changing the ylimits just spans the full figure height no matter what limits I choose.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from matplotlib import rcParams

x = np.array([3500])
y = np.array([0])

rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'

plot.figure(num=None, figsize=(4, 1), dpi=80, facecolor='w')
plot.axes(frameon=False)
plot.yticks([0])
plot.xlim(0, 6000)
plot.ylim(-0.1, 0.1)
plot.plot(x, y, 'x', markersize=10)

plot.show()
```

Current figure:

[image: Current figure]

Desired figure:

[image: Desired figure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply changing `figsize` to `(4, 0.3)`, I get something that more or less looks like your desired output (except with ticks at the top as well, but those can also be removed):

[image: Output]

Comment: Are you on Windows? When I run that on Windows, it still cuts out the bottom axis marks for me.

Comment: Yes, that was on Windows. What if you combine, say, a `figsize` of `(5, 0.5)` with a `plot.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)`?

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
plot.ylim(lower_limit, upper_limit)
```

Where `lower_limit` is the value you want to set for the bottom of the `y-axis` and `upper_limit` is the value for the top.

```
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)

plot.figure(num=None, figsize=(4, 1), dpi=80, facecolor='w')
plot.axes(frameon=False)
plot.ylim(-10, 10)
plot.plot(x, y, '.')
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but no matter what limits I use, it still fills the figure. Since this is just a 1D plot, I want the height to shrink.

Answer (score 3):

The code in the question already produces the desired result, when adding 
`plot.tight_layout()` at the end.

[image]

Of course decreasing figure size even further, shrinks the plot even more. E.g.
`figsize=(4, 0.7)`

[image]