# How to create multiple 1D axes showing intervals with colored lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, intervals

I want to visualise mathematical domains, or intervals. Equivalently, I want to visualise a boolean array. There are multiple such arrays, that ideally are plotted one above the other.

What I have is some data: several recordings, over a period of, say, 100 min. Each recording satisfies a given condition only part of the time. I want to visualise the times at which each recording is "True". Some simpler variant of:

[image: 1D axes example]

In my case, each recording can be the union of multiple intervals. For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

sb.set_context("paper")

times = np.arange(0, 100)

mask1 = (times >= 0) * (times <= 30) + (times >= 70) * (times <= 100)
mask2 = (times >= 20) * (times <= 80)
```

I can plot each recording separately, with these two functions I have written:

```py
def bool2extreme(mask, times) :
    """return xmins and xmaxs for intervals in times"""
    binary = 1*mask
    slope = np.diff(binary)

    extr = (slope != 0)
    signs = slope[extr]

    mins = list(times[1:][slope==1])
    maxs = list(times[:-1][slope==-1])

    if signs[0]==-1:
        mins = [times[0]] + mins

    if signs[-1]==1:
        maxs = maxs + [times[-1]]

    return mins, maxs

def plot_interval(mask, times, y=0, color='k', ax=None) :

    if ax==None:
        print('None')
        ax = plt.gca()

    xmins, xmaxs = bool2extreme(mask, times)

    for xmin, xmax in zip(xmins, xmaxs):

        ax.plot([xmin, xmax], [y,y], lw=6, color=color)

    return ax
```

**My problem is to control the vertical spacing between the various intervals**. Indeed, when I plot one of them, there is a vertical axis which I don't want. Even if I set its visibility to False, it exists and takes space. So, when I put each recording on a different subplot, the vertical spacing between them is much too big:

```py
masks = [mask1, mask2]
labels = ['domain1', 'domain2']
n_plots = len(masks)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(n_plots, sharex=True)

for i, mask in enumerate(masks) :

    axs[i] = plot_interval(mask, times, ax=axs[i])

axs[-1].set_xlabel('Time (min)')

sb.despine()
```

[image]

Another option I tried: have all the intervals in the same axis, but at different y values. But the problem of the vertical spacing between the intervals remains the same.

```py
masks = [mask1, mask2]
labels = ['domain1', 'domain2']
n_plots = len(masks)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(sharex=True)

for i, mask in enumerate(masks) :

    ax = plot_interval(mask, times, y=i, ax=ax)


ax.set_xlabel('Time (min)')

ax.set_yticks(range(n_plots))
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.grid(axis="x")

sb.despine(left=True)
```

[image]

How can I control the vertical spacing between these intervals?

Comment: It does not answer my question unfortunately. I can plot one horizontal line, that is not my question. My question is: when I want to plot multiple horizontal lines, how can I control the vertical spacing between them (which by default is too big)?

Comment: It is true, and I can control the location of the horizontal lines on the y-axis in my second example as well. But my problem remains. In the second example, I set "domain1" at y=0, and "domain2" at y=1. But if I want them closer and set y=0.1 for "domain2", matplotlib will scale my y-axis, so that the vertical lines will be closer in data units, but in physical units the will still be at the same large distance from each other. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

- figsize with a small height when creating the subplots; the height of figsize controls the distance between the horizontal axes: they will be `height/num_axes` separated when measured in inches
- `ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)` to hide the ticks from the y-axis
- `ax.spines['left'].set_color('None')` to make the spine of the y-axis invisible
- `ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))` to place the x-axis at the `y=0` height
- (optionally) `ax.tick_params(labelbottom=True)` to have labels for the xticks on all subplots (instead of only on the last)
- use a rectangle instead of a thick line to better control the exact start and end of the line as well as the thickness above and under the axis
- to control the height of the rectangle, the ylims need to be fixed; I propose `(-1.5, .5)` so a thickness can be chosen appropriately; there is more space below making room for the labels of the xticks
- as drawing a rectangle doesn't automatically update the xlims, they need to be set explicitly
- (optionally) `ax.tick_params(which='both', direction='in')` to get tick marks above instead below (both mayor and minor ticks)

To have labels on the left, the following worked for me:

```
# ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  # removed, as it also hides the ylabel
ax.set_ylabel('my ylabel', rotation=0, ha='right', labelpad=10)
ax.set_yticks([])  # to remove the ticks, the spine was already removed
```

In the demo code, more xticks and some type of arrow at the ends are added. There are 7 masks in the demo, to better see the effect of distance between the axes. Trying to get the axes as close as possible, a distance of 0.4 inches seems doable. (The `bool2extreme` function is untouched, as it is closely related to the format used as input.)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, Polygon
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
import seaborn as sbs

sbs.set_context("paper")

times = np.arange(0, 101)
num_masks = 7
masks = [np.zeros_like(times, dtype=bool) for _ in range(num_masks)]
for i in range(num_masks):
    for j in range(50):
        masks[i] += (times >= (i+3)*j) * (times <= (i+3)*j+i+1)
masks = masks[::-1] # reverse to get the masks plotted from bottom to top

def bool2extreme(mask, times) :
    """return xmins and xmaxs for intervals in times"""
    binary = 1*mask
    slope = np.diff(binary)

    extr = (slope != 0)
    signs = slope[extr]
    mins = list(times[1:][slope==1])
    maxs = list(times[:-1][slope==-1])
    if signs[0]==-1:
        mins = [times[0]] + mins
    if signs[-1]==1:
        maxs = maxs + [times[-1]]
    return mins, maxs

def plot_interval(mask, times, xlim=None, y=0, thickness=0.4, color='k', ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['left'].set_color('None')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('None')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('None')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', 0))
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=True)  # to get tick labels on all axes
    # ax.tick_params(which='both', direction='in')`  # tick marks above instead below the axis
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plticker.MultipleLocator(base=10)) # major ticks in steps of 10
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plticker.MultipleLocator(base=1))  # minor ticks in steps of 1
    ax.set_ylim(-1.5,.5)
    if xlim is None:
        xlim = (times[0]-0.9, times[-1]+0.9)
    ax.set_xlim(xlim)
    xmins, xmaxs = bool2extreme(mask, times)
    for xmin, xmax in zip(xmins, xmaxs):
        #ax.add_patch(Rectangle((xmin, y-thickness), xmax-xmin, 2*thickness, linewidth=0, color=color))
        ax.add_patch(Rectangle((xmin, y), xmax-xmin, thickness, linewidth=0, color=color))
    triangle1 = [(xlim[0]-0.5, y), (xlim[0], y-thickness), (xlim[0], y+thickness)]
    ax.add_patch(Polygon(triangle1, linewidth=0, color='black', clip_on=False))
    triangle2 = [(xlim[1]+0.5, y), (xlim[1], y-thickness), (xlim[1], y+thickness)]
    ax.add_patch(Polygon(triangle2, linewidth=0, color='black', clip_on=False))
    return ax

n_plots = len(masks)
dist_between_axis_in_inches = 0.4

fig, axs = plt.subplots(n_plots, sharex=True, figsize=(10, dist_between_axis_in_inches*len(masks)))
for i, mask in enumerate(masks) :
    axs[i] = plot_interval(mask, times, xlim=(times[0]-0.5, times[-1]+0.5), ax=axs[i], color='lime')
axs[-1].set_xlabel('Time (min)')
plt.show()
```

Result with axes close together:

[image: resulting plot]

PS: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737736/matplotlib-axis-arrow-tip) contains more proposals about adding arrows.

Comment: Additional ideas at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699759/how-do-you-limit-the-y-axis-height-in-matplotlib

Comment: Thanks! Adjusting the figsize seems to be the best we can do. In the same idea, I'm also using `axs[i].set_aspect(40)`. They're both a bit frustrating though because it's not a direct control of the vertical distance between the subplots, and more like guess work. To try having more direct control, `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=-0.1)` can somewhat help. Finally, `plt.tight_layout()` can also do a good job in combination with the others, although it changes the figsize which I don't like.

Comment: One more question: right now, the thick plotted line is going partly under the spine. How can we have it not crossing the spine, but vertically aligned with it, for a given linewidth?

Comment: Probably by drawing a filled rectangle instead of a thick line. You'd need to set the y-axis to some fixed limits (e.g. -1,1) to control the rectangle height. I would leave out the `set_aspect(40)`, as it heavily depends on the range of the x-axis.